# Sub-string representation — length or pointer to last byte?

Tags: c

Imagine parsing a string and wanting to extract a sub-string. To represent this sub-string, I see two ways:

```
// 1. represent it using a start pointer and a length
struct { char *start; size_t length; };
// 2. represent it using two pointers, start and end
struct { char *start; char *end; };

// or it could as well be returned by a function:
char *find_substring(char *s, size_t s_len, size_t *substring_len);
char *find_substring(char *s, size_t s_len, char **substring_end);
```

Is there a reason to prefer one form over the other? Is it only down to preferences? I don't see it affecting performances as one can be translated into the other using a simple addition/subtraction but I might be wrong.

The context is an HTTP request parser if that changes anything. I used the first one but I'm curious if the second one brings anything to the table as I have seen it used in picohttpparser.

Comment: If `end` is specified to point to the last byte of a substring (not one beyond it), there is no way to represent a null substring when `start` points to the first byte of an array, since `end` would have to point to `start-1`, which is not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a reason to prefer one form over the other?

One could choose optimization and speed of execution as the measure of preference over on the other.

If more often you append data on the end, then `*end++` would be faster over `start[length++]`.

If more often you get the length of the string, then just `length` would be faster then `end - start`.

Remember about [rules of optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub). The only real answer comes from profiling your code.

> Is it only down to preferences?

I advise to prefer the more appropriate representation to the problem you are trying to model, based on how readable it is, how easy it is to use it and find bugs in it, which comes down to personal preference.

We could also inspect existing implementations. In C, all(all?) C standard functions and in POSIX like [strbuf](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), [aiocb](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), [XSI messages queues](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), [iovec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) use pointer+integer to represent a memory region. I think all C++ implementations of `std::vector`, like [glibc std::vector](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h#L93) or [llvm vector](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/vector#L342), use pointers *internally*, but one can expect they be optimized for `push_back()` operations.

Generally I lean over to use pointers. When operating on `size_t` you have to handle overflow and underflow and negative/too big values or converting from pointer difference `ptrdiff_t` to `size_t`. Such problems kind-of disappear with pointers - a pointer is either valid, or not, you need only bound check using `<` `>` operators if you may in-/decrement it or not. However when writing an external api, I would use `size_t`, as C programmers are used to represent memory region using that convention.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases this would be down to personal preference. I guess most people choose the first representation. But depending what you plan to do with that substring the second implementation may be better performance-wise.

With the second implementation you have to be specific about where `end` points to: is it the last character still in substring or the first character beyond substring.

Comment: Could you give an example of a situation where the second implementation would be better performance-wise? I would assume that the benefit of avoiding an addition if using the first representation and wanting a pointer to the end of the string is completely hidden by the cost of mov.

Good point about the second representation being ambiguous.

Comment: `for ( const char *substChar = start; substChar != end; substChar++ ) do_something(*substChar);`
vs
`for ( const char *substChar = start; substLen > 0; substChar++, substLen-- ) do_something(*substChar);` I hope the missing parts are selfexplanatory.

Answer (score -1):

The first way is preferred way. For example, consider that you have to deal with very large strings. Then it will not remain a simple allocation of bytes. In that case you have to represent it in a more complicated manner.

The second way leaks the information about internal representation of string while the first does not.

Comment: I don't see how a (start, length) pair is capable of representing something more complicated than just a byte array. Having special bytes that indicate a redirection? Not a fan